# ionic start app error shell.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create new ionic app and cmd show error below :

```
D:\CODE\PROJECT-P>D:\CODE\PROJECT-P>ionic start firstapp tabs                                                                             
shell.js: internal error                                                                                                
Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\shelljs_866e2b9163335638d2c5'                         
at Error (native)                                                                                                       
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:502:18)                                                                                    
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1103:15)                                                                              
at execSync (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:67:57)                 
at Object._exec (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:179:12)           
at Object.exec (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:168:23)           
at Object.getCordovaInfo (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:50:24)                                                                                                                      
at Object.gatherInfo (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:241:8)                                                                                                                          
at Object.checkRuntime (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:288:19)                                                                                                                       
at Object.doRuntimeCheck (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:558:10)
```

Anyone know what wrong with my ionic? or my setting my ionic setting error?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you look at this : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1165 ?